# SSIS - XML Task - XSLT operation

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, ssis

I have value (integer) in variable from SQL Server.

And XML file with a lot of elements. One of these elements had one value. And I need to replace (change) this value to my variable value.

I don't know how to use XML Task - XSLT Transformation.

For example:

> Variable value: **12345**
> XML element: < Element>**00000**</ Element>

And I need:

> < Element>**12345**< /Element>

Thanks for your tips and tricks!

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you. --- Hint: this is a trivial task. Start with the *identity transform* template and add a template matching the element you want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really asking is how to pass a parameter in SSIS to XML Task, XSLT operation.

Unfortunately, XML task functionality is somewhat limited. It doesn't accept any XSLT parameter.

There are few simple ways to overcome such limitation:

1. SSIS Script Task that implements XSLT transformation with parameter(s).
2. SSIS Script Task, XML modification via LINQ to XML API.
3. Etc.

Here is how to do it via method #1. You would need to pass four parameters to the SSIS Script Task. Three of them for the XML/XSLT/XML files, and the last one is your SSIS variable.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
   const string SOURCEXMLFILE = @"e:\Temp\UniversalShipment.xml";
   const string XSLTFILE = @"e:\Temp\UniversalShipment.xslt";
   const string OUTPUTXMLFILE = @"e:\temp\UniversalShipment_output.xml";
   bool paramXSLT = true;

   try
   {
      XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
      if (paramXSLT)
      {
         // Create a parameter which represents the current date and time.
         DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
         xslArg.AddParam("date", "", d.ToString());
      }

      using (XmlReader src = XmlReader.Create(SOURCEXMLFILE))
      {
         XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
         xslt.Load(XSLTFILE, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());

         XmlWriterSettings settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
         settings.IndentChars = "\t";
         // to remove BOM
         settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

         using (XmlWriter result = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUTXMLFILE, settings))
         {
            xslt.Transform(src, xslArg, result, new XmlUrlResolver());
            result.Close();
         }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("File '{0}' has been generated.", OUTPUTXMLFILE);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```